# Trying to sum a joined subquery

Tags: sql-server

For my sql class I am trying to write a query that sums a column in a sub query. The Sub query has a calculated value in it and I am trying to total that calculated value for particular zipcodes.
the query runs without errors but the output is null in the sum column

Tried running the sub query on its own and the value is calculated for the column properly

```
select c.CustomerState
,c.CustomerZip
,sum (b.TotalSales)as Sales
from [DBM460LearningTeam].[dbo].[TBLcustomer]as c
Left Join (select v.CustomerNumber
    ,sum (v.QuantitySold * i.ItemPrice) as TotalSales
    from TBLinvoice as v
    inner join TBLitem as i
    on v.ItemNumber = right(i.ItemNumber,3) 
    group by v.CustomerNumber) as b
on c.CustomerNumber = b.CustomerNumber
group by c.CustomerZip , c.CustomerState;
```

I want to sum the total sales by zipcode so i expect to see column for zipcode and column for state and column for sales  and thats what I get but the sales column is Null all the way down.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `CREATE` statements for the tables and some `INSERT` statements for sample data. And the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: your query looks legit pragmatically.. if all `Sales` column `NULL` *may be* that because your sub query return no data.. and *may be* related to `on v.ItemNumber = right(i.ItemNumber,3)`.. why `right(i.ItemNumber,3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CustomerNumbers aren't lining up on your join on. I would verify that that part if you say you have a value for TotalSales when you just run the subquery. I bet if you changed that left join to an inner join you would get nothing. So you are getting all values from TBLCustomer but nothing matches on customernumber when you do the left join.

Comment: thanks, That seems to be the problem. If i change to inner join i get no rows and if i change to a right join i get nulls in the state and zip but a lump sum for sales so the data tables must have different values for the customer number.  I ran into that issue on the Items table vs the invoice table. the item number had a leading digit on one of the tables. Hence right(i.ItemNumber , 3)    Thanks